# Using retrieved information from method of other class

Tags: java, postgresql, arraylist, data-retrieval

I have retrieved data in below class from PostgreSQL database, successfully. The rows of table data in PostgreSQL are add in `ArrayList<> userlist`.
I shared the corrected codes.

```
class UserList extends ArrayList<User> {
// as in comments said it seems really bad idea is to extend ArrayList. So, avoid it!
    }
```

The User class is:

```
public class User {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

       public User(String firstName, String lastName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public void calculateSimilarityUser(User u){
            .... //some codes                
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        } 
    }
```

The UserDAO class is:

```
public class UserDAO {

    static Connection currentCon = null;
    static ResultSet rs = null;

    private ArrayList<User> userlist = new ArrayList<>();

    public ArrayList<User> LoadFromDatabase(){

        PreparedStatement userinfoStmt = null;

        String loadUsersInfo = "SELECT * FROM userinfo";

            try {
                currentCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
                userinfoStmt = currentCon.prepareStatement(loadUsersInfo);
                rs = userinfoStmt.executeQuery();


                while (rs.next()) {
                    User us = new User(rs.getString("firstname"), rs.getString("lastname"), rs.getInt("index"));


                userlist.add(us);
            }

            userinfoStmt.close();
            currentCon.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        return userlist;   
    }
```

The index.jsp

```
<%

                UserDAO inf= new UserDAO();
                ArrayList<User> userList = inf.LoadFromDatabase();
                Recommender rc = new Recommender(userList);
   %>
```

Comment: What's null? You're calling the unconventionally-named `LoadFromDatabase()` method, but not actually doing anything with the reuslt, as far as I can see. (You're also swallowing exceptions, and not creating a new list on each call, which seem to be a bad idea, but that's different matter.)

Comment: Another really really bad idea is to extend ArrayList. That's useless, and makes it confusing for you. The list of users is the list **returned** by the `users.LoadFromDatabase()` method. Not the users object itself. And all those instance variables should be local variables of the method.

Comment: Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extending ArrayList does not make any sense in your case. Basically you can name your class `UserDAO`. And no need to create class level variables, you can create local variables.

```
public class UserDAO { // no need to extend and changed name to UserDAO

    public List<User> retainTopUsersItems(int maxNumOfReturnedResources, List<User> userList) {
        List<User> retainList = new ArrayList<User>();
        for (int i = 0; i < maxNumOfReturnedResources; i++) {
            retainList.add(userList.get(i));
        }
        return retainList;
    }

    public List<User> loadFromDatabase() {
        Connection userinfoCon = null;
        ResultSet userinfoRS = null;
        List<User> userlist = new ArrayList<>();
```

In you jsp use retrieved list from method.

```
<%
    // UserList users = new UserList();
    UserDAO inf= new UserDAO();
    List<User> userList = inf.loadFromDatabase(); // See the changes
    Recommender rc = new Recommender(userList); // Change constructor definition in your Recommender
%>
```

**Note:** Do not consume your exception either throw it or log it?

Comment: but i am working with `ArrayList<User>` in some situations and cant remove it. I have a User class that introduce users specification and `ArrayList<User>` do somethings on these users. Should i use a new class for retrieving users from database?

Comment: I am not telling you to remove `ArrayList<User> userlist = new ArrayList<>();`, I am just telling you to remove `extends ArrayList<User>`. And no need to create new class, your existing class is doing that only.

Comment: This will not give you required functionality or I would say your logic is not right. You should pass arraylist to this method and use it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I add more codes to understand better. I want insert `ArrayList<User> userList` into `UserList users` :| How can do that?!

Comment: Why don't you add `retainTopUsersItems` method in userDAO and remove your UserList class. See my updated answer. I don't see any usecase of extending ArrayList and using that class.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your knowledge with me. It really helped me.